# RGB to GRAY using opencv removes 1 channel

Tags: keras, rgb, grayscale

I'm using these for convertin RGB image to GRAY

```
i = cv2.resize(img, (100, 100))
i = cv2.cvtColor(i, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

This gives me (100,100) but I want (100,100,1) as this is required as input to CNN as follows

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, (2,2), input_shape=(100,100,1 ), activation='relu'))
```

Show how should I convert RGB to GRAY such that 1 channel factor remains retained.

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy reshape:

```
i = i.reshape(i.shape + (1,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the extra dimension
`np.expand_dims(i, axis=0)`

Comment: This isn't strictly correct for what the question is asking for. The extra dimension must be added at the end, not as the first dimension. The correct axis is -1, e.g. `np.expand_dims(i, axis=-1)`

Answer (score 0):

Using ellipses and `np.newaxis` can you more a readable code compared to `np.expand_dims` or `reshape`.
Here's the one-liner, it is easy to see that the new dimension will be added to the last dimension.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

i = cv2.cvtColor(i, code=cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)[..., np.newaxis]
```